# Data frame creation from an input file

Tags: python, input, pandas

I have a file which contain some floating values like

```
5.234234
6.434344
5.45435
7.243224
4.0999884
```

I want to create a dataframe from this file.It should look like

```
Activity
5.234234
6.434344
5.45435
7.243224
4.0999884
```

What I've tried is(its not working)

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
data= open('Activity.txt').read()
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),names='Activity',header=None)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You must use:

```
p.read_csv('Activity.txt', names=('Activity',))
```

Note:
1) You dont need to *open* your file.
2) `names` is 'array-like', for example, a tuple or list.
3) `header` is `None` by default when `names` parameter is specified (otherwise 0).

Comment: If you specify `names` you also don't need `header=None`